# how do I display more posts with paging in wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress

I am developing wordpress website where i display the latest 3 posts items (based on category) in the home page and i want to give "more news" link to view all the posts with paging in separate page .. How can I display it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
query_posts( 'cat=-category_id&posts_per_page=3' );
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
the_title();
the_content( 'Read the full post »' ); or the_excerpt();
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
<a href="pass category url">Caegory Link</a>
?>
```

For Paging u can use wp page navi plugin.